# Como é feito o envio de dados POST do front para o Back

Tags: rest, post

estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com nodeJs/express e me deparei com o seguinte problema
como é feito o envio dos dados do front para o back

Ao utilizar o postman que é utilizado para testar as requisiçoes eu consigo chegar a um resultado satisfatorio porem me deparei que existem varios tipos de envio de dado como por exemplo:

- form-data
- x-www-form-urlencoded
- raw
- binary
- GraphQl

e o que me chamou mais atenção é que dentro de raw existe outros sub tipos

- Text
- Javascript
- Json
- Html
- XML

para poder proseguir meus estudos gostaria de esclarecimentos no fato de o que é:

form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded, raw,binary, GraphQl
(o conceito de cada um mais geral)
( e de forma mais tecnica qual o nome correto a esse tipo de coisa .... se é protocol, codificação )

grato pela atenção

Comment: Acabo de descobrir que em js existe um objeto chamado XMLHttpRequest que fornece funcionalidade ao cliente para transferir dados entre um cliente e um servidor.

Comment: é feito com um `request`, pode ser o que comentou, era essa a dúvida? tem muitos exemplos aqui no site de como funciona